# Need help sorting data and computing averages

Tags: python, list, file, sorting

I need to create a code that will run like this when executed :

```
What would you like to do: s

You have selected Statistics

This option is for viewing statistics sorted by the year of student.
Please select one of the following options: 
a for ALL YEARS
b for FRESHMAN
c for SOPHMORES
d for JUNIORS
e for SENIORS

Enter your choice here: e

For Seniors:
High/Low/Mean of all Weighted Scores:  89.53999999999999 /  81.60000000000001 / 86.15736842105264
High/Low/Mean of all Lab Averages:  89.6 / 80.2 / 86.21052631578948
High/Low/Mean of all Program Averages:  94.33333333333333 / 77.0 / 86.78947368421052
```

It should take information from a file and separate the scores by grade in order to calculate. How do i separate the data by grade of the student to calculate the averages ? Completely clueless here.

The first number after the name is the grade

```
   Ablao 3 74 96 72 88 71 80 83 77 90 88 95 71 76 94 80 74 98 77 
   Anderson 3 76 92 98 95 92 76 93 97 85 76 85 93 82 88 75 84 92 77 
   Aspinwall 1 86 74 78 97 86 94 73 95 74 91 75 94 83 99 83 78 88 96
```

Code I have written so far

```
All_Years=[]
Freshman=[]
Sophomores=[]
Juniors=[]
Seniors=[]

def make_lists_of_status():
    if (student_status==1):
        Freshman.append(student_scores)

    elif (student_status==2):
        Sophomores.append(student_scores)

    elif (student_status==3):
        Juniors.append(student_scores)

    elif (student_status==4):
        Seniors.append(student_scores



def statistics_func():
    user_stat_choice='x'
    print("This option is used for viewing statistics sorted by the year of the student")
    print("Please select one of the following options:")
    print("(a) for All Years, (b) for Freshman, (c) for Sophomores, (d) for Juniors, (e) for Seniors")
    user_stat_choice=print(input("Enter your choice here:"))

    if(user_stat_choice=='a'):
        print ("Hi/Low/Mean of all weighted scores  is:",max(All_Years),min(All_Years),(sum(All_Years)/len(All_Years)))
        print ("Hi/Low/Mean of all lab averages is:")
        print ("Hi/Low/Mean of all program averages is:")
```

Comment: you basically want to calculate for example `Ablao = 3+74+96... /number_of_grades` ?

Comment: No, for example 74,76, and 86 (2nd number of each row) is homework grade. I need to calculate the max, min and average out of Ablao and Anderson for homework grade since they are both in grade 3 (same 1st number) @GLHF

Comment: What type, list? string? For example Ablao's grades are in a list ?

Comment: Do you have any code that you wrote  ?

Comment: "It should take information from a file " ? a text file? and the output you provided is in the file, line by line?

Comment: Im assuming that I would need to make lists for each grade maybe ? That will hold all the scores for students of that grade? But don't know how to go about doing it so that it has the outcome I want @GLHF

Comment: @HassanMehmood I have written some code but I think it is wrong I will edit post to include

Comment: @Rachel Please be more specific, do you take that scores from a txt file?

Comment: @GLHF Yes those scores are coming from a .txt file.  There is scores for 60 students. I already have a function that sorts scores and puts them into a list based on student name but don't know how to do this as for grades collectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
ablao = [3,74,96,72,88,71 ,80 ,83 ,77 ,90 ,88 ,95 ,71 ,76 ,94 ,80 ,74 ,98 ,77]
anderson = [3,76 ,92 ,98 ,95 ,92 ,76 ,93 ,97 ,85 ,76 ,85 ,93 ,82 ,88 ,75 ,84 ,92 ,77]
aspinwall = [1,86 ,74 ,78 ,97 ,86 ,94 ,73 ,95 ,74 ,91 ,75 ,94 ,83 ,99 ,83 ,78 ,88 ,96]

for dat1,dat2,dat3 in zip (ablao,anderson,aspinwall):
    if dat1 == dat2:
        secondGrade1 = ablao.index(dat1)+1
        secondGrade2 = anderson.index(dat2)+1
        break
    if dat1 == dat3:
        secondGrade1 = ablao.index(dat1)+1
        secondGrade3 = aspinwall.index(dat3)+1
        break
    if dat2 == dat3:
        secondGrade2 = anderson.index(dat2)+1
        secondGrade3 = aspinwall.index(dat3)+1
        break
try:
    print (ablao[secondGrade1])
    print (anderson[secondGrade2])
    print (aspinwall[secondGrade3])
except:
    pass
```

Put them into a list, then use `zip()` to check if their first elements are met. If they are, define the indices of that variables and break the loop.

Output;

```
>>> 
74 #only ablao's and anderson's first elements are same
76 #
>>>
```

After then is just basic math (calculate average etc.)

Comment: There are 60 names in total , i only included 3 as a sample. Would this method still work ? @GLHF

Comment: If you do this on all of them, yes.

Answer (score 0):

To read the file of student information do

```
with open('/path/to/scores.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

You can then loop through all lines you just read from the file and extract the relevant information. `line.split()` splits a line into a list of strings at the whitespace characters and the `name, grade, *scores` notation makes use of a Python 3 feature to elegantly unpack that list into individual variables. The next line is there to convert the scores from a list of strings to a list of ints.

```
for line in lines:
    name, grade, *scores = line.split()
    scores = list(map(int, scores))

    if grade == '1':
        Freshman.append(scores)
    elif grad == '2':
        Sophomores.append(scores)
    ...
```

From there you should be able to use the code you already wrote.

PS: Since the unpacking notation is not available in Python 2 in that form, you could use the following if you are using that version:

```
for line in lines:
    split_line = line.split()
    name = split_line[0]
    grade = split_line[1]

    scores = map(int, split_line[2:])
    ...
```